Ordering transactions by ModifiedDateTime, having issues when some transactions with the same workid have the same ModifiedDateTime
I am trying to order work transactions by modifiedDateTime. Currently I am using Row_Number() and Partitioning to order the transactions and then selecting only records where rn = 1.
Shown below:
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY [AX].[WHSWorkLine].[WorkId] 
    ORDER BY [AX].[WHSWorkLine].[MODIFIEDDATETIME] DESC
) AS [rn]

My issue is that workers have been 'picking' and 'putting' very quickly so that the two transactions are recorded in the same exact second. If the two most recent transactions were performed in the exact same second and consist of worktypes 'pick' and 'put', the 'put' record should be prioritised in the ordering.
I have three examples below of how the ordering should work in different scenarios:



WorkID
WorkType
ModifiedDateTime
rn




1
different type
2024-01-01 11:00:00
1


1
put
2024-01-01 12:00:00
2


1
pick
2024-01-01 12:00:00
3






WorkID
WorkType
ModifiedDateTime
rn




1
put
2024-01-01 12:00:00
1


1
pick
2024-01-01 12:00:00
2






WorkID
WorkType
ModifiedDateTime
rn




1
pick
2024-01-01 11:00:00
1


1
put
2024-01-01 12:00:00
2



I tried to order them based on work type using a case expression, but this ordered all the 'put' transactions at the top even if there were other WorkType transactions that occurred more recently.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

So, add a ,case when worktype = 'put' then 0 else 1 end after the modifieddate desc? What's the real problem

what is the exact datatype of ModifiedDateTime ?

datetime2(7) would be pretty rare to have collisions.


If the two most recent transactions were performed in the exact same second and consist of worktypes 'pick' and 'put', the 'put' record should be prioritised in the ordering.

You can include this in the ORDER BY clause with a CASE expression after the existing order:
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY [AX].[WHSWorkLine].[WorkId] 
    ORDER BY [AX].[WHSWorkLine].[MODIFIEDDATETIME] DESC, 
        CASE WHEN [AX].[WHSWorkLine].[Worktype] = 'put' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
) AS [rn]

